# Updating error for a given query

Tags: oracle

If the following query is written, I'm getting the error invalid B.WO_NO. If the query is written without the WHERE clause, all the amount values in work_order_coding_tab is said updated. But I don't need to update all the data in the table. But instead I need to update only rows select by , the inner select. Any suggestions for what I can tried out. Please help

```
UPDATE work_order_coding_tab A
A.amount = (SELECT B.sales_price_amount
                     FROM work_order_coding B
                     WHERE A.WO_NO = B.WO_NO AND
                     A.ROW_NO=B.ROW_NO  
                     AND B.work_order_cost_type_db = 'M'
                     AND B.order_no IS NULL
                     AND B.catalog_no IS NOT NULL        
                     AND A.amount is not null and A.amount <> B.sales_price_amount and B.contract like 'TZ%'  
                     and abc.active_separate_api.get_line_no(B.wo_no) =2)
 WHERE A.WO_NO = B.WO_NO AND
       A.ROW_NO=B.ROW_NO
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even need the current outer `WHERE` clause, i.e. just use this:

```
UPDATE work_order_coding_tab A
SET A.amount = (SELECT B.sales_price_amount
                FROM work_order_coding B
                WHERE
                    A.WO_NO = B.WO_NO AND
                    A.ROW_NO = B.ROW_NO AND
                    B.work_order_cost_type_db = 'M' AND
                    B.order_no IS NULL AND
                    B.catalog_no IS NOT NULL AND        
                    A.amount IS NOT NULL AND
                    A.amount <> B.sales_price_amount AND
                    B.contract LIKE 'TZ%' AND
                    abc.active_separate_api.get_line_no(B.wo_no) = 2)
```

The error is happening because the alias `B` does not exist and is not available outside of the subquery.  But your `WHERE` logic inside the correlated subquery already does what the outer `WHERE` clause attempts to do.

Note that you might actually want an outer `WHERE` clause, e.g. if you wanted to restrict the updating of amounts to certain records in the `work_order_coding_tab` table.  Typically, it is best practice to have some restriction on an update, unless of course you really intend to update the entire table.

Comment: Hi Thanks, for replying. Yes I need to update a certain records in the work_order_coding_tab . The work_order_coding view has WO_NO and ROW_NO. I need to take those values and update only the records in work_order_coding_tab which are equal to  WO_NO and ROW_NO. These WO_NO and ROW_NO only should be taken from a select written as above. (The inner query). Any suggestion how I can do it?

Comment: @user3789200 - For every row in `work_order_coding_tab a`, having `A.WO_NO and A.ROW_NO`, which are not null, the update will be successful, because `B.sales_price_amount` is taken from those records in `work_order_coding B`, which have correspondence to the exact `A.WO_NO and A.ROW_NO` of `work_order_coding_tab a`. You're safe to go.

Comment: Ah ok. The select query has only 12 rows selected. But in the update, it is said 540 are updated which is the number of rows in the work_order_coding_tab. It means , though this message appeared only the 12 records will be updated in the work_order_coding_tab? but how does it select the exact rows when no where conditions are availabl. Sorry for the ignorance